# Librero problema al alinear elementos div y aplicarles z-index

Tags: html, css

Estoy tratando de hacer un librero usando `CSS` el problema surge al alinear elementos con `display:inline-block` no funciona, los demás elementos aparecen verticalmente (trato de hacerlos horizontal) y tambien el `z-index` no lo puedo aplicar a la clase `.libro` aparentemente el elemento queda detras.

**¿Cómo podría alinear los elementos horizontalmente?**

**¿Cómo aplicar `z-index` correctamente?**

```css
.gabinete {
 width: 100%;
 height: 615px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: #45221c;
 top: 40px;
 left: 30%;
 border: 10px solid #69342b;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px 0px #21100d;
}
.gabinete .base-arriba {
 width: 104%;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #572b23;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 top: -20px;
 left: -2%;
 position: absolute;
}
.gabinete .divicion {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 33.5%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gabinete .divicion .atras {
 position: absolute;
 display:inline-block;        /*no funciona*/
 top: 0;
 left: 2%;
 width: 96%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #2c1512;
 box-shadow: inset 10px 15px 15px #21100d;
}
.gabinete .divicion .base {
 width: 100%;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom: 20px solid #331915;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 bottom: 10px;
 position: absolute;
}
.gabinete .divicion .frente {
 width: 100%;
 height: 10px;
 background-color: #69342b;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
}
.libro{
 width: 25%;
 height: 80%;
 margin: 2px;
 background-color: yellow;
 z-index: 100;                /*no funciona*/
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px 0px #21100d;
}
```

```html
<div class="gabinete">
 <div class="base-arriba"></div>

 <div class="divicion">
  <div class="triangulo-der"></div>
  <div class="triangulo-izq"></div>
  <div class="atras">
      <!-- aqui agrego los libros -->
   <div class="libro">libro</div>
   <div class="libro">libro</div>
   <div class="libro">libro</div>
   <div class="libro">libro</div>
  </div>
  <div class="base"></div>
  <div class="frente"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="divicion">
  <div class="triangulo-der"></div>
  <div class="triangulo-izq"></div>
  <div class="atras">
  </div>
  <div class="base"></div>
  <div class="frente"></div>  
 </div>
 <div class="divicion">
  <div class="triangulo-der"></div>
  <div class="triangulo-izq"></div>
  <div class="atras">
  </div>
  <div class="base"></div>
  <div class="frente"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La propiedad `z-index` sólo afecta a elementos que han sido posicionados (que tenga posición absolute, relativa o fixed). Como no has especificado ninguna posición para los `.libro`, no le afectará y quedarán detrás de los otros estantes del librero.

Entonces, para que se vean bien, además de añadir `display:inline-block` (para que se alineen horizontalmente) también debes poner un `position:relative` (para que aplique `z-index`):

```css
.gabinete {
 width: 100%;
 height: 615px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: #45221c;
 top: 40px;
 left: 30%;
 border: 10px solid #69342b;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px 0px #21100d;
}
.gabinete .base-arriba {
 width: 104%;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #572b23;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 top: -20px;
 left: -2%;
 position: absolute;
}
.gabinete .divicion {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 33.5%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gabinete .divicion .atras {
 position: absolute;
 display:inline-block;        /*no funciona*/
 top: 0;
 left: 2%;
 width: 96%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #2c1512;
 box-shadow: inset 10px 15px 15px #21100d;
}
.gabinete .divicion .base {
 width: 100%;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom: 20px solid #331915;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 bottom: 10px;
 position: absolute;
}
.gabinete .divicion .frente {
 width: 100%;
 height: 10px;
 background-color: #69342b;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
}
.libro{
 width: 25%;
 height: 80%;
 margin: 2px;
 background-color: yellow;
 z-index: 100;                /*no funciona*/
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px 0px #21100d;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="gabinete">
 <div class="base-arriba"></div>

 <div class="divicion">
  <div class="triangulo-der"></div>
  <div class="triangulo-izq"></div>
  <div class="atras">
      <!-- aqui agrego los libros -->
   <div class="libro">libro</div>
   <div class="libro">libro</div>
   <div class="libro">libro</div>
   <div class="libro">libro</div>
  </div>
  <div class="base"></div>
  <div class="frente"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="divicion">
  <div class="triangulo-der"></div>
  <div class="triangulo-izq"></div>
  <div class="atras">
  </div>
  <div class="base"></div>
  <div class="frente"></div>  
 </div>
 <div class="divicion">
  <div class="triangulo-der"></div>
  <div class="triangulo-izq"></div>
  <div class="atras">
  </div>
  <div class="base"></div>
  <div class="frente"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```